# 音声録音時のエラーについて

Tags: swift

音声を録音(.wavで)するアプリで、録音ボタンを押すと、下記のエラーが出てしまいます。
教えていただける方がいましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。ちなみに、音声の拡張子なのですが、.cafの場合はエラーになりません。しかし今回は.wavで保存したいです。

追記　エラーが出る場所は以下のとおりです。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var PlayBTN: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var RecordBTN: UIButton!

    var soundRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
    var SoundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

    let fileName = "audioFile.wav"//ここがwavの場合のみエラーがでる。

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        setupRecorder()
    }

    func setupRecorder(){


        let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(8000.0)),
            AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless)),
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 2),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue))];

        var error: NSError?

        do {
            //  soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject])
            soundRecorder =  try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            soundRecorder = nil
        }

        if let err = error {
            print("AVAudioRecorder error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            soundRecorder.delegate = self
            soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        }
    }

    func preparePlayer(){

        var error : NSError?

        do{
            SoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: getFileURL())
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            //error = error1
            SoundPlayer = nil
        }

        if let err = error {
            print("AVAudioPlayer error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            SoundPlayer.delegate = self
            SoundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            SoundPlayer.volume = 1.0
        }
    }

    func getCacheDirectory() -> String {

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as [String]

        return paths[0]
    }



    func getFileURL() -> NSURL{
        //let path  = getCacheDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let path  = (getCacheDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        //let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename))
        return filePath
    }

    @IBAction func Record(sender: UIButton) {

        if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Record"{

            soundRecorder.record()
    //ここでEXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)というエラーが出てしまいます。

            sender.setTitle("Stop", forState: .Normal)
            PlayBTN.enabled = false   
        }
        else{

            soundRecorder.stop()
            sender.setTitle("Record", forState: .Normal)
            PlayBTN.enabled = false
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: シミュレータで実行したら、エラーになるということですか？シミュレータで録音はできない（ちなみに、カメラ撮影もできない）ので、エラーになるのは、むしろ自然な結果といえます。実機でテストした結果はどうですか？

Answer (score 1):

wavファイルで録音したい場合、recordSettingsのAVFormatIDKeyはkAudioFormatLinearPCMじゃないでしょうか？